# R- mongolite on OS X Sierra- No suitable servers found

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

I am trying to follow the "[Getting started with MongoDB in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mongolite/vignettes/intro.html)" page to get a database up and running. I have mongoDB installed in my PATH so I am able to run `mongod` from the terminal and open an instance. Though when I open an instance in the background and try running the following commands in R:

```
    library(mongolite)
    m <- mongo(collection = "diamonds")    #diamonds is a built in dataset
```

It throws an error after that last statement saying:

```
    Error: No suitable servers  found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [Failed to resolve 'localhost']
```

How do I enable it to find the connection I have open? Or is it something else? Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to connect using a MongoDB GUI, such as [robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) ?

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect using that. I hadn't used that robomongo GUI before but I downloaded it and got it to work and show all my collections.

Comment: Did you ever get this working, Vince? I'm going through the same thing. I've installed mongo and have it running, am able to make a connection in the terminal  but get the same error as you where trying to make a connection from R with the mongolite package.

Comment: Check your version of mongolite. I tried just about everything from SO and Github with this error before upgrading the mongolite version from 1.5 to 2.2.0 in my Dockerfile...older versions of mongolite struggled connecting to Mongo clusters on Atlas.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that mongolite is looking in the wrong place for the local server. I solved this same problem for myself by explicitly adding the local host address in the connection call:

```
 m <- mongo(collection = "diamonds", url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1")
```